# LM317 Vout instability under load

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, lm317

I hooked up a 9 V power supply to a LM317 (the power supply provides enough current, 2 A, and its heatsink is present) since I need to get 5.1 V in order to power a Raspberry Pi.

The Raspberry boots up, but the LM317 gets too hot and it shuts down.

I lowered the LM317’s Vin to 7.5 V even though is below then 3 V headroom. It still gets warm (still quite too much in my opinion,) but it works and it doesn’t shut down.

Monitoring the voltage (and receiving low power alerts from the RPi) I can see that the output voltage of the LM317 is not stable and during boot. When I push a bit the Raspberry, it goes widely down until 4.80 V.

The power supplies that are sold for the RPi are rated 5.1 V but I never had any issues with those. If I monitor their voltage out, they provide 5.18 V and swing at maximum 5.16 V.

What is my LM317 doing wrong? Am I missing something?   Is it because of low headroom?

I also tried to place a 10 uF capacitor (even higher) at the voltage regulator output but it didn’t solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Is your load current really 2A?  If you it could just be dissipation in the regulator and you may need a heatsink.  Could also be a layout issue.  How close are your input and output caps to the pins of the regulator? How about the divider resistors? Can you show a picture of your setup?

Comment: Even at 7.5V you are burning about 5W if the RPi draws 2A.   The only explanation is that your heatsink is not big enough to dissipate the heat.

Also, you didn't specify the package for the LM317, some packages have pretty high thermal resistance, even with a heatsink.

Comment: Just get one of those 2A drop-in linear regulator replacements for $5 and save yourself the hassle of trying to dissipate 5W out of a TO-220.

Comment: That definetly sounds like a too small heatsink. Did you use some thermal paste or anything similar? What is the thermal coefficient of your heatsink? Just try a larger heatsink and it will propably work.

Comment: LM317 is unstable with only 100nF at the output, and your heat sink is probably too small.

Comment: Which exact LM317 model you are using? Most of them are not rated for 2A.

Comment: the LM317 exact model is https://www.taydaelectronics.com/datasheets/A-177.pdf
I'm not drawing 2A but around 600mA (average Rapsberry Pi current consumption).

the package is TO-220.
I can't show a picture since everything is on breadboard, i was just testing.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry pi typically draws 0.5A with no accessories attached. Dropping your 9V to 5v = 4V drop across the LM317.  4V drop x 0.5A = 2Watts.

If you use 7.5V supply, drop is 2.5 and current is still 0.5A so you have 1.75W dissipated by the LM317. Still too much - if I recall correctly, most TO220 packages are limited to 1.5W.

Voltage can be low because the protection circuit in the LM317 will throttle back current to lower the package temperature.

Also, the LM317 is only 5% accuracy per output volt (50mV/V).  At 5V, expect 0.25v fluctuation plus any error from the resistors you used (5% tolerance resistors are typical but errors can multiply if one voltage-setting resistor is 5% below target and one is 5% above target.

Finally,get a small SMPS module to regulate voltage. It will be much more efficient in the voltage conversion.

Comment: Will try with a big heatsink and check what happens.
The small SMPS modules don't allow you to get exactly the output voltage you desire though.
At least, this is what i know